# How do I update a Listbox Index with a Timer output

Tags: vb.net, vba, timer, listbox, listboxitem

I am fairly new to coding with Visual Basics. I am working on a project were I need to create multiple items in a list and at the end of each list have a timer count up individually for when the Start button is pressed.
Currently the problem is that I have been unable to update the index when the timer increases its count.
[Form Design Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFWRX.png)
I have listed my code below. Any feedback on how to achieve this will be much help.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As Object
    Dim count As Object

    Public Sub GlobalTimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        count.Text = Val(count.Text) + 1
        ListBox1.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        count = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        count.Text = 0
        t1 = TextBox1.Text
        t2 = TextBox2.Text
        t3 = TextBox3.Text
        t4 = TextBox4.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add("P" + t1 + " - " + t2 + " - " + t3 + " - " + t4 + " - " + count.text)

        If (t1 = "") Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a P-Level number.")
        ElseIf (t1 = 0) Then
            Timer1.Start()
        ElseIf (t1 = 1) Then

        ElseIf (t1 = 2) Then

        ElseIf (t1 = 3) Then

        ElseIf (t1 = 4) Then
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Please explain in more detail!  Will you have multiple entries/lines in your ListBox?  Which line(s) with their counters need to be updated.  Explain what is going in with the "t" values.

Comment: The list box will have multiple lines. The t values represent the text box in order from left to right ( see picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFWRX.png ) and the input for them.                    t1   - t2 - t3 - t4 - count.text
Example: Hello - 3 - David - Description - "Timer"

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure if I understand correctly...but try this to start out with:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Entries As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of Entry)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.DataSource = Entries
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ent As New Entry
        ent.T1 = TextBox1.Text
        ent.T2 = TextBox2.Text
        ent.T3 = TextBox3.Text
        ent.T4 = TextBox4.Text
        Entries.Add(ent)
    End Sub

    Private Class Entry

        Public T1 As String
        Public T2 As String
        Public T3 As String
        Public T4 As String
        Public Shared Counter As Integer

        Private Shared Delimiter As String = " - "

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return "P" & T1 & Delimiter & T2 & Delimiter & T3 & Delimiter & T4 & Delimiter & Counter
        End Function

    End Class

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Entry.Counter = Entry.Counter + 1
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = Entries
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you